# iOS Swift vs Node JS Crypto Different Outputs

Tags: ios, node.js, swift, encryption

I am not sure what's wrong with my Node JS Code. The output from Node JS lacks some characters than the output in iOS Swift.

My Node JS Code:

```
var crypto              = require('crypto');

var CRYPTO_ALGORITHM    = "aes-256-ctr";
var CRYPTO_PASSWORD     = "3zTvzr3p67VC61jmV54rIYu1545x4TlY";
var CRYPTO_IV           = "0123456789012345";

var string_data = "OLIVER MARTINEZ OLIVER";

var cipher      = crypto.createCipheriv(CRYPTO_ALGORITHM, CRYPTO_PASSWORD, CRYPTO_IV);
var encrypted   = cipher.update(string_data, "utf8", "hex");
encrypted       += cipher.final("hex"); // to hex

console.log("encrypted final: " + encrypted);

// --------------------------------------------------------------- //

var encrypted_string = encrypted;

var decipher    = crypto.createDecipheriv(CRYPTO_ALGORITHM, CRYPTO_PASSWORD, CRYPTO_IV);
var decrypted   = decipher.update(encrypted_string, "hex", "utf8"); 
decrypted       += decipher.final("utf8"); // to utf8

console.log("decrypted final: " + decrypted);
```

NODE OUTPUT: 3df3cfd9adef86489fd27629d75f3fcbb744e5bae846

My iOS Swift Code:

```
let CRYPTO_IV           = "0123456789012345";
let CRYPTO_PASSWORD     = "3zTvzr3p67VC61jmV54rIYu1545x4TlY";

let data                = "OLIVER MARTINEZ OLIVER";

let encrypted = try! data.encrypt(AES(key: CRYPTO_PASSWORD, iv: CRYPTO_IV, blockMode: .CTR)).toHexString();

print("encrypted: \(encrypted)");
```

IOS SWIFT OUTPUT: 3df3cfd9adef86489fd27629d75f3fcbb744e5bae846bde7df9e98571ba27f01

As you can see. The output is very similar. Only the NodeJS output lacks some characters.

Answer (score 1):

[CTR mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Counter_.28CTR.29) is a streaming mode which doesn't require any padding. It seems that [CryptoSwift](https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/CryptoSwift#aes) always adds padding, even if a streaming mode like CTR is used. You need to request that no padding will be applied in Swift:

```
data.encrypt(AES(key: CRYPTO_PASSWORD, iv: CRYPTO_IV, blockMode: .CTR, padding: NoPadding())).toHexString();
```

Comment: Please note that `NoPadding()` **cannot** be called outside the `CryptoSwift` module currently (due to lack of public initializer of `NoPadding`).

I've opened a [pull request](https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/CryptoSwift/pull/254) and it's merged into `develop` branch and will be released in the near future (hopefully).

Comment: Thanks a lot Artjom.. I also had the error when using the NoPadidng().. I'm glad it's not just me and it will be resolved soon. Thanks a lot sir. Really helpful